# LINQ Left and Right Join Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

This is my sql query, how can I generate this query into LINQ:

```
SELECT 
    TimeTable.StartTime,
    sum(Booking.Quantity) as Total
FROM PromotionSlot
RIGHT JOIN TimeTable
ON PromotionSlot.StartHour = TimeTable.StartTime
LEFT JOIN Booking
ON PromotionSlot.ID = Booking.PromotionSlotID
GROUP BY TimeTable.StartTime
```

Result:

```
|StartTime    |Total|
---------------------
 9             NULL
 10            NULL
 11            2
 12            2
 13            NULL
 14            NULL
 15            NULL
 16            NULL
 17            NULL
 18            NULL
 19            NULL
 20            NULL
 21            NULL
```

This is what I attempted, I'm not sure that the structure of the linq is correct with my SQL query. But I faced error about `The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.` Please guide me, thank you all in advance!

```
var bookingdata = 
    (from ps in dc.PromotionSlots
     join t in dc.TimeTables on ps.StartHour equals t.StartTime into Ts
     join bo in dc.Bookings on ps.ID equals bo.PromotionSlotID into Bs
     from time in Ts.DefaultIfEmpty()                         
     from book in Bs.DefaultIfEmpty()
     group new {time,book} by time.StartTime into NewGroup
     select new dataView
     {
         StartTime = NewGroup.Key,
         numBookings = NewGroup.Select(a => a.book!=null? a.book.Quantity: 0).Sum()
     }).ToList();
```

Here is my `dataView` model

```
public class dataView
{
    public int? StartTime { get; set; }
    public int? numBookings { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

changed `StartTime` in my dataView model to `int?` and this is the result by using `console.log()`

```
Format: @:console.log("* " + "@item.StartTime" + ":" + "@item.numBookings");
* :0
* 10:0
* 11:2
* 12:2
```

I found out the reason why the above `console.log()` will appear this result. I tried to change my SQL Query `RIGHT JOIN TimeTable` to `LEFT JOIN TimeTable`. The return result totally the same like the output from my LINQ.

Comment: Just curious, is there a particular reason you are doing a RIGHT JOIN? It seems to me that you only add to the confusion by doing that rather than being consistent with LEFT JOIN as they are virtually interchangeable.

Comment: @jwatts1980 because I'm trying out different of join and find out this approach is the one that I wanted. That's why I use this, kindly check my updated question I found out that in my `LINQ` both `JOIN` are `LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` & `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: Ok. Most advice I've received from SQL admins over the years is, not so much to avoid right joins, but to be consistent with one or the other in queries. I see LEFT JOIN used far more often. Most people tend to think "I want table X to be the main data set, and I want to get from table Y only where there are matches to X" (which describes a left join).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're hitting is that in ad-hoc query results, any column value can be null (eg., the Total column in your results example has mixed values, int and null). But C# is not so lenient, an a null value cannot be stuffed into a integer value.

I think that in your `dataView` type, the `numBookings` property is probably set to `int`, and an `int` type in C# is not nullable.

I believe if you change it to a nullable int, like:

```
public int? numBookings { get; set; }
```

then that may fix your error. If not that, then the following *might* work:

```
numBookings = NewGroup.Select(a => a.book!=null ? (a.book.Quantity ?? 0): 0).Sum() ?? 0
```

But I am not sure about this last one.

**UPDATE**

What if you update your LINQ query to use LEFT JOIN for both joins, like so:

```
var bookingdata = (
    from t in dc.TimeTables 
    join ps in dc.PromotionSlots on t.StartTime equals ps.StartHour into Ts
    from time in Ts.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join bo in dc.Bookings on time.ID equals bo.PromotionSlotID into Bs
    from book in Bs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new {time, book} by time.StartTime into NewGroup
    select new dataView
    {
        StartTime = NewGroup.Key,
        numBookings = NewGroup.Select(a => a.book!=null? a.book.Quantity: 0).Sum()
    }
).ToList();
```

Does this make the results more consistent with the SQL query?

Comment: Hi, @jwatts1980 inside my `dataview` model `numbookings` is already `int?`

Comment: @J4X Could update the question with that class definition.

Comment: @J4X I have updated my answer. Please see that I added `(a.book.Quantity ?? 0)` to the second example. `a.book.Quantity` may be null.

Comment: I faced this error `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'`

Comment: @J4X Okay... now that you have updated your answer, it appears that perhaps the error is not in the numBookings part, but in the StartTime part. Your console log shows that one of your start times appears to be null, which may be the part that is throwing the error. Did you receive the error when you update the StartTime to `int?`?

Comment: if the `StartTime` is `int` after I debug and went to the view it shows `IOE was unhandled by user code: The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null.` But if changed it to `int?` problems solved, but the first line of `StartTime` gone missing.